# Oracle timestamp with timezone in where clause issue

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, to-timestamp

I have the following sql query with

```
select * from MY_TABLE
 MY_COL >= to_timestamp_tz('08-03-17 07:25:00.0000 EST', 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff TZR') and 
 MY_COL <= to_timestamp_tz('08-03-17 09:08:00.0000 EST', 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff TZR')
```

Where there are atleast the following 2 entries(as displayed in sql developer).

```
03-AUG-17 07.25.51.576000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK
03-AUG-17 07.31.33.553000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK
```

My query returns no entries. I would expect to get both these entries back. Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

thanks

Comment: It looks like you may have mixed up your dd and mm specifiers.  Your format is probably mm-dd-yy in this case.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to avoid the date format ambiguity by using [timestamp literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062): `MY_COL >= TIMESTAMP '2017-08-03 07:25:00 EST' and ....`. (And as a further aside, make sure you really mean both `>=` and `<=`, and that you don't accidentally overlap ranges when running multiple times.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look closely at this

```
MY_COL >= to_timestamp_tz('08-03-17 07:25:00.0000 EST', 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff TZR') and 
 MY_COL <= to_timestamp_tz('08-03-17 09:08:00.0000 EST', 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff TZR')
```

The date string is: `'08-03-17 ...` and the format string is: `'dd-mm-yy ....`

- dd- is DAY  = 08
- mm - is MONTH = 03
- yy - is YEAR = 17

Please check in [the documentation: format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

So, your query is looking for dates that are:

- greater than `08-MARCH-2017 07:25`
- lower than `8-MARCH-2017 09:08`

It's not a big surprise that the query doesn't find these records:

```
03-AUG-17 .....
03-AUG-17 .....
```

since AUGUST is not MARCH

Comment: this is very embarassing. Thanks for point out the glaring issues here.